# Where do accents come from? I am not just talking about American accents

Tags: pronunciation

Where do accents come from? If I was speaking with a Mexican person that spoke English, I would not understand them.

Comment: I have no trouble understanding most accents, including people who have English as a second language. Like a really thick and fast Welsh accent might give me trouble, but otherwise, I don't struggle to understanding anyone. As to where they come from: English is not fixed, it is influenced by its local environment. Like Darwin's finches. The birds' beaks and feathers are ever so slightly different on every island.

Comment: http://linguistlist.org/ask-ling/accent.cfm

Comment: Your accent comes from the people from whom you learned your language. But you are not talking about accents per se, which everyone on this earth who speaks has. You are talking about a person's accent in a non-native language. I wonder if you speak a language other than English? Probably not or you would not have asked this question. If you do, I bet you have a foreign accent in whatever that language is....pshaw.

Comment: This isn't really a question limited to English. It might be on-topic on [Linguistics.SE], as accent is probably a product of sounds in the foreign language not mapping entirely on to the native language, so they are made to fit. For example, [this question](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/486) does mention English, but its principles are more widely applicable.

Comment: @Andrew Leach I do not think I would call it mapping, which sounds like the subject (human being) has been "deleted" from the picture. In any case, when you say  "accent is probably a product of sounds in the foreign language not mapping entirely on to the native language", I think you meant:  "a [foreign] accent is probably a product of native-language sounds being reproduced in a person's non-native language".

Comment: @Lambie That's exactly what I said. The sounds in the foreign language do not occur in the native language, so those foreign sounds are forced into the square holes of the native language. Thus a Frenchman speaking English will tend to use his native French sounds (because he cannot use English sounds, so he has to approximate), producing a French accent. Ditto an Englishman speaking French. Reading your answer, I think we agree.

Comment: @Andrew Leach It is the other way around. You have now said it twice. The sounds from the native language (French) are forced INTO English by the Frenchman. Or conversely, the sounds from English (by an English speaker) are forced INTO French by the Englishman. But I prefer to say: The sounds from the native language come through in the foreign language the person is trying to speak. The directionality is what you are mis-expressing. (Sorry, but as a quadri-lingual, I do know about this.) One attempts to speak the other language but the native language seeps through in pronunciation.

Comment: I do think we're actually saying the same thing. In attempting to make an English sound, the Frenchman has to resort to a French sound, because he can't -- or doesn't know how to -- make the English sound, as those sounds don't occur in French. Thus the sounds from French appear in his spoken English, giving a French accent. Which is what I said: the sounds of English don't appear in French [English sounds do not map on to French sounds], so the Frenchman has to resort to putting French sounds in his spoken English, resulting in a French accent. But it's not good to split hairs in comments.

Comment: @Andrew Leach In your examples, I agree. But I do not agree with way non- example statements. I was not splitting hairs. I was just clarifying: "so those foreign sounds are forced into the square holes of the native language".

Comment: The foreign sound he should say ends up being approximated as a sound he can say (from his native language).

Answer (score 2):

Your accent (one's accent) comes from the people from whom you (one) learned your (one's) language (the speech community, linguists say). But the OP is not talking about native speaker accents per se, which everyone on this earth who speaks has.

**The OP is talking about a person's accent in a non-native language**. I wonder if he speaks a language other than English? Probably not or he would not have asked this question. If, however, he does, I bet he has a foreign accent in whatever that language is. This question has zero  to do with English. It has universal application.

Here's the basic rule which anyone who learns a second language or speaks more than one language is familiar with: **One's accent in a second language when it does not sound like the other community of speakers of that language (in other words, it sounds foreign in that language) is dictated by one's native or original language**. Of course, there are those who can learn to speak another language without sounding like a foreign speaker. Usually, they learn the language at a young age. Those who learn another language at a later age very often do sound like foreign speakers of it. French speakers can detect English speakers, German speakers can detect English speakers and so on. I say detect to mean: if they have been exposed to that other language, they can usually detect when a German speaker is not native, for example.

An accent in a foreign language can go from very light to very heavy. And sometimes understanding a person with a heavy accent can be a challenge.

It should give us pause to remember that despite appearances, English is not the center of universe. Imagine all the Russians who speak Chinese, or all the Arabs who speak Amharic. Gives one pause, doesn't it.....

Comment: I've always wondered what an English accent sounded like to foreigners and got a small insight when speaking (very bad) French to some French people in Cyprus. They asked me whether I was English or German so I now know that a northern English accent and a German accent sound similar to French speakers. At least it's a start!

Comment: @BoldBen Indeed it is. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the example of the person born and raised in Mexico, struggling to make himself understood in English.

Those who are raised speaking Spanish learn to use their tongue and lips and other parts of the speaking apparatus differently than English speakers do.  Here are a few of the differences:

- For *t*, the tip of your tongue touches the back of your upper teeth
- Your vowels will be "pure".  For example, when *e* appears in a word, it will be pronounced similar to "eh", a word used by Canadians.  When *a* appears, it will sound similar to the *a* in "father."
- You won't have gotten comfortable pronouncing words starting with "sp" or "st".  When you encounter English words that start this way, you will naturally add an *e* at the beginning, to make the word pronounceable for you.
- You will be accustomed to rolling your *r*'s.
- You won't be used to some of the vowels commonly used in English, such as the short *u* in *lunch*.
- etc.

It is natural for these pronunciation habits to persist when the person tries his hand at speaking English.

Note, one learns the pronunciation patterns needed for one's native language at the parents' knee.

Keep in mind that there is a mirror image problem.  You can easily hear this if you listen to someone from the U.S. struggling to make himself understood in a foreign language.

Except the difference there is that most Mexicans are easy going and tolerant of foreigners who mispronounce a good deal of their Spanish words.

Note that through careful attention to how the tongue, lips, etc., are used, along with the intonation, or "music" of the target language, one can often eliminate the "foreign accent."

When a child learns a second language thoroughly, from a native speaker, before the age of 8, he will probably have little or no "accent."  Effortlessly.

Comment: I thought Canadian "eh" is pronounced "ey", as a diphthong

Comment: Those who are raised speaking [whatever language] learn to use their tongue and lips and other parts of the speaking apparatus differently than [whatever other language] speakers do. Accents do not persist for everyone. And that 8-year-old rule is just wrong.

Comment: @Lambie - I don't understand your comment.  I observed that a child who learns a second language well, before age 8, will *usually* speak it without an accent.  Is your opinion that even under-eights in fact do have an accent?  Or are you saying you think 8 was a badly chosen number?  //  What is your first point?  Your sentence looks the same as what I wrote, only that I took as an example the nationality referenced by the OP.  What am I not getting?

Comment: @sumelic - I posed your question: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/363302/112436.  I thought that *eh* was pronounced as a dipthong in the U.S. but I thought that it was different in Canada.  Hopefully the question I asked will clear this up!

Comment: @aparente001 Small kids pronounce any language fine. Also, it is NOT true that one cannot learn another pronunciation system with no accent after the age of 8. Your first sentence could be read as not applying to other language pairs. My point is that this scenario applies to any language pairs. All languages have their own points of articulation (which is what causes an accent in any language).

Comment: @Lambie Thanks for explaining. I agree that small children tend to figure out how to produce specific sounds easily. It doesn't always work perfectly -- hence we have speech-language specialists in schools. // You have misunderstood my statement about under-eights.  I'm not saying one can't acquire a native accent after age 8, but that it is more effortless before age approximately 8 -- which I think is your belief as well. // I chose the specific example as an attempt to make my answer more accessible to the OP. // My answer seems to have been quite irritating for you; I am sorry about that.

Comment: @aparente001 No worries. Speech therapy is not the subject we are discussing. Any kid can learn any language, until they become overly self-conscious. That is really what stops people. They feel odd or embarrassed. Kids don't care. They just parrot what the hear. So, you can take three-year old with English-speaking parents and plunk them down in Beijing and presto they'll be speaking Chinese in no time. At their level of course...

Comment: @Lambie - My experience with my polyglot children has been *mostly* what you described.  However, things do not always go perfectly swimmingly.  For example, one, at age three, was having trouble with the Spanish R.  I temporarily modeled a more throaty R for him.  It was helpful.  On our next trip to Mexico, friends teased us gently about his "French" accent (we were living in France) or his "German" accent (my spouse is German), but they understood him well.  After another few months, the child successfully made the transition to a proper Spanish R. // I only mentioned speech-language ...

Comment: ... specialists to make the logical point that, as I think we both agree, small children are amazingly good at figuring out what to do with their tongue, lips, etc., to be able to imitate specific sounds, BUT it's not an infallible process.

Comment: I like everything about this answer, and I think it's spot on, but I don't like the tacit implication that while Mexicans are tolerant of foreign accents, Americans aren't. I am an American and critique of someone's accent doesn't even *occur* to me, let alone disparaging someone because of it (listen: if you have a foreign accent, you speak *at least* one more language than you do, so my position is I'm on the back foot, not you). If that part were removed, I'd upvote this asnwer.

Comment: @DanBron - OP's expectation is that s/he won't understand someone with a Mexican accent.  Or did I misread the question?

Comment: @aparente001 Yes, but that's OP. Your answer reads "the difference is Mexicans [are not jerks about foreign accents]". That is an odd way to phrase "the difference between Mexicans [and you] is...", if that's what you intended. The way it's phrased it sounds like the contrast you're setting up is between Mexicans and Americans, not Mexicans and OP. And if you are saying that Americans in general are jerks about foreign accents, that's what I disagree with and take exception to.

Comment: (Worth pointing out I've travelled my share and the default I've seen, almost everywhere, rural US included, is that people are charmed by someone putting in effort to speak their language, and generally don't care a whit about errors. I make a *mess* of Spanish, but I've spoken it from Spain to Venezuela to Mexico to randos I meet in Brooklyn, and no one has ever given me static about it. Same with my, if possible, even more horrible French. And same I've seen for tourists talking to locals in the US.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50062/discussion-between-aparente001-and-dan-bron).